# how to link (with mklink) existing 'pictures' folder with already existing 'pictures' folder in onedrive

Tags: onedrive, hardlink, mklink

This might sound a bit complicated. I need to explain the history of my problem.

1. Few years ago I found a helpfull hint to get your local pictures folder included in onedrive by adding a hard link with mklink. This worked fine!
2. For some (dumb) reason I yesterday didn't remember the smart solution and deleted the 'pictures' shortcut (mklink result) from the onedrive folder.
3. Onedrive asked me: do you want to remove all the pictures from onedrive? I realised I made a mistake and chose 'recover'. Onedrive did this, but... made a normal folder 'pictures' in my onedrive folder.
4. So now I have  c:\users\myname\pictures   AND  c:\users\myname\onedrive\pictures. These folders are now independant from each other. I want the latter be a mklink folderlink to the first.

What I Tried:

1. remove the pictures folder in onedrive and replace it with a mklink shortcut. That doesn't work, because onedrive wants to remove all pictures from cloud (and that 250Gb). Even when pausing syncing, that doesn't work
2. create a new symbolic link in onedrive: c:\users\myname\onedrive\picturesmirror  ; pause syncing; create the same folder oneline in onedrive;  move online all files from pictures to picturesmirror. Resume syncing. That doesn't work: onedrive says: there are local folders in picturesmirror with same name (duh.. that's what I intended..) and onedrive renames all the local folders to xxxxx_localcomputername.

Of course I can remove everything from onedrive and start over with the mklink, but I'ld like to avoid the 250gb upload.

Any smart clues?

Appreciated!

Comment: Added comment: Is it maybe a solution to unlink onedrive from my onedrive folders, replace the pictures folder by it's symbolic equivalent with mklink /j  and relink it? As far as I know, onedrive matches on filename and size, so it will be 'fooled'. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes writing down a question helps the brain to find the answer.
This was the case for me with the above question. I found the answer which was simple and effective:

- unlink onedrive (this will remove all non downloaded file-links from the system, but that's not a problem)
- wait until onedrive has executed all its tasks. This may take a while
- delete the c:\users\username\onedrive\pictures folder
- in cmd execute mklink /j c:\users\username\onedrive\pictures c:\users\username\pictures (or your pictures path)
- relink onedrive . You will be prompted for the onedrive path, chose the same path as before.

Now the pictures folder will be matched by onedrive. I.e.: onedrive will be fooled because of the nice properties of the link.